# Turbolinks Android Adaptor - back button where to start

Tags: android, back, turbolinks, adaptor

Very new to Android development and the Android adaptor for Turbolinks 5. I have written a small application that loads the website, clicking links works OK however pressing the back button on the phone; navigates back a page but then none of the links work and I can't swipe down to refresh.

Any ideas on where I need to start looking would be appreciated. Not sure what is even helpful to quote of the code I've done already but think this is the main bit:

```
public static Stack<String> intent_history = new Stack<String>();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Find the custom TurbolinksView object in your layout
    turbolinksView = (TurbolinksView) findViewById(R.id.turbolinks_view);

    // For this demo app, we force debug logging on. You will only want to do
    // this for debug builds of your app (it is off by default)
    TurbolinksSession.getDefault(this).setDebugLoggingEnabled(true);

    // For this example we set a default location, unless one is passed in through an intent
    location = getIntent().getStringExtra(INTENT_URL) != null ? getIntent().getStringExtra(INTENT_URL) : BASE_URL;

    // Execute the visit
    TurbolinksSession.getDefault(this)
            .activity(this)
            .adapter(this)
            .view(turbolinksView)
            .visit(location);
}


public void visitProposedToLocationWithAction(String location, String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(INTENT_URL, location);

    intent_history.push(location); // Added to support UPDATE below

    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

UPDATE - Realise it was the need to override the onBackPressed method. I have something like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

        if (intent_history.isEmpty()) {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(INTENT_URL, intent_history.pop());

            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

The finish and exit does not work and also I have to hit back twice for it to pop the current screen off but it roughly works and I will refine when I need to (just a test of concept at the moment).

Comment: I've got exactly the same problem.  Have you had any luck with this?  I'm using Bootstrap for my layout and was wondering if this could be related?

Comment: I have. Using the visit callback above I pushed the location to a stack... then using the back button callback I pop the last location and start that as an activity. When back in office I'll add more details.

Answer (score 1):

After a little searching this is what I'm using to get up and running.

```
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    TurbolinksSession.getDefault(this)
            .activity(this)
            .adapter(this)
            .restoreWithCachedSnapshot(true)
            .view(turbolinksView)
            .visit(location);
}
```

I'm just getting started so any comments/corrections would be great.